# How to setup subpath proxy in nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy

## My upstream server running on PORT - `3000`

```js
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.get('/test',function(req,res){
  res.send('<h1>Testing...</h1>')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 3000...')
})
```

I can easily see both routes in the browser

[image]

[image]

### Setting up the proxy from ngnix -> Node

I tried the following configurations

```js
location ^~ /* {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/$1;
}

========================================
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}

========================================
location /* {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/$1;
}
```

All the above configuration is loading `http://localhost/` but 404 on `http://localhost/test`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try_files`serves static files. Remove this line.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
```